# Open Uri to read JSON file in background task UWP

Tags: windows, uwp

I have a use case where I have to read a config.json file from an AppService and based on the configuration in json file I have to generate an ID.
I am using following piece of code to generate the Uri so that I can open the file using StorageFile.GetFileFromApplicationUriAsync(fileUri).

```
Uri fileUri = null;
        try
        {
            Debug.WriteLine("Creating new uri");
            fileUri = new Uri(fileName);
            if (fileUri == null)
            {
                Debug.WriteLine("Uri creation failed");
            } else
            {
                Debug.WriteLine("New Uri created");
            }
        } catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine("Uri creation failed" + ex.Message);
        }
```

Now when I am trying to debug this code my debugger is disappearing after line with `new Uri(fileName)`
If I just let the code run with no breakpoints I am not seeing any message after **Creating new uri**. Not even an exception.

Value of `fileName` is "ms-appx:///config/config.json"

Can anyone please explain what is wrong here? Also is it possible to open and read a file from an AppService?

--
Thanks
Tarun

Answer (score 0):

The uri use appx only can read the resource is content in msbuild.

You can right click the file and select the property and you should select the file's build action as content.

http://jycloud.9uads.com/web/GetObject.aspx?filekey=449e34647d61faca2ce846b773a4da8e

http://jycloud.9uads.com/web/GetObject.aspx?filekey=5423b79037eee8dc66431d0478d79871

http://jycloud.9uads.com/web/GetObject.aspx?filekey=6189eb9547c6f2fa79333df67ab33cef

You can see the last image is use complie and you can change it to content.

Sorry, my visual studio's language is local language.But the visual studio's have the same layout.

Comment: Thanks for replying. Actually problem is not in reading file. I tested that with unit tests. I am able to read file properly. It is failing when activating from AppService.

Comment: Sorry for can not help you.The code not run in new uri and I think it cant creat a uri,and sure "ms-appx:///" fileName is right.